# Passing kwargs in a class inheritance chain

Tags: python, inheritance, keyword-argument, method-resolution-order

I have the following setup:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    # Some variables initialized
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, k, v)

class B(A):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    A.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    self._b = {}
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, k, v)

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self._b.update(value)

class C(B):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    B.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    # Some variables initialized
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, k, v)
```

When I now create a new instance of `C` I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute '_b'
```

Now this makes sense since `B._b` hasn't been initialized when `A.__init__(self, **kwargs)` is being called. I can resolve this issue simply by re-ordering the B's initialization like so,

```
class B(A):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self._b = {}
    A.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, k, v)
```

I'd like to understand if there is a recommended/best practice approach when I need to pass `kwargs` from child to parent classes during initialization? It seems to me like the following things would work,

1. Re-order the initialization like I have above
2. Assign `kwargs` in each child class then pop them and pass the remaining `kwargs` along to the parent initialization
3. Something better

Hoping to get some approaches for 3.

Comment: *"When I now create a new instance of C I get the following error"* I don't get an error. [mcve]?

Comment: @Aran-Fey you're right I apologize I didnt include the property setter that was the source of the error I provided. Class B above also does the following,     ```@property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self._b.update(value)```

Comment: The loops you have in all your `__init__` methods looping over `kwargs` seem redundant to me. Why do you want to do that in every class? Either just do it once, or don't do it at all (and have each class accept whatever named arguments it expects and only use `kwargs` for arguments intended for parent classes. Please [edit] the question to put the information about the `b` property into the main question. It doesn't make any sense without that information, so it shouldn't be left in a comment.

Comment: I did update it after my comment above @Blckknght. Will respond further to your answer below

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is with these loops:

```
for k, v in kwargs.items():
    setattr(self, k, v)
```

You have one in each class, and that means that *every* one of the classes is setting *all* the keyword arguments as attributes on `self`.

When that loop runs in `A`, it fails because `B` has a property that needs initializing before it can work.

As you noted in the question, a quick fix would be to make sure that `B` sets up its dictionary before it runs `A.__init__`:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        _b = {}                        # set this up first
        A.__init__(self, **kwargs)     # before calling the superclass
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
```

But there's probably a better approach that would let you avoid the redundant loops. I'd suggest explicitly naming the keyword arguments you expect in each class. That way `b` will only be seen by the `B` class, not by `A`, nor `C` (except as part of `kwargs`).

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, *, a): # a is keyword-only arg, no kwargs accepted here
        self.a = a

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *, b, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs) # doesn't mess with b!
        self._b = {}
        self.b = b

    @property
    def b(self):
       ...

class C(B):
    def __init__(self, *, c, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.c = c
```

Now you can call `C(a="foo", b={1: 2}, c="bar")` and each class will only pay attention to the attribute it cares about.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Blckknght. The reason for the loops was simply for classes that had a lot of attributes that would need to be assigned when initialized.

Comment: Editing my comment further here since my 5min ran out. So it seems like if I wanted to keep the benefit of assigning multiple attributes using the loop then perhaps initializing `B` by first doing `_b = {}` might be my best option.

Comment: I should add that adding the loop that assigns attributes based on the kwargs makes it cleaner to have default values specified in the initialization and still be able to assign a non-default value if passed in. The other option of course is to specify all parameters and their defaults in `__init__` but that is much less compact

Comment: If you really want to let all the arguments be caught up in `kwargs`, then just make sure there's only one loop assigning them to attributes (probably in the base class). The downside to this approach is that there's no easy way to have mandatory arguments. If there's no useful default for `a`, say, you can't enforce that without an `if 'a' in kwargs` check that is uglier than just having it as an explicit argument. Similarly, its impossible to prevent unknown arguments to be passed in (perhaps due to typos). If you call `C(A='foo')` you may not realize for a while that you miscapitalized `a`.